# Actionscript 3 FlvPlayback with XML and For-Loop

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, for-loop, flvplayback

I have a aplication and I want to have as many FLV players(to play only one video each) as I want, controled by XML. I control some variables (skin color, player x and y, etc).
My code is working but with some problems, so I need help to optimize my code.
One of the problem is on videos fullscreen, I put one video in Fullscreen, and the other goes to full screen...and other problems with skin alpha, autoplay happens too..

**My AS3**

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarMode;

var my_videos:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;
var my_player:FLVPlayback;
var player_skin_color:Number;
var player_skin_alpha:Number;
var auto_play:Boolean;

var videoArray:Array = new Array();

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {

 var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

 my_videos = myXML.VIDEO;
 my_total = my_videos.length();

makePlayer();
positionPlayer();
}


function makePlayer():void {

 for (var i:int = 0; i < my_total; i++) {

 my_player = new FLVPlayback();
 my_player.skin = "SkinOverPlayFullscreen.swf";
 my_player.skinBackgroundColor = player_skin_color;
 my_player.skinBackgroundAlpha = player_skin_alpha;
 my_player.autoPlay = auto_play;

 player_skin_color = my_videos[i]. @ PLAYER_SKIN_COLOR;
 player_skin_alpha = my_videos[i]. @ PLAYER_SKIN_ALPHA;
 auto_play = my_videos[i]. @ VIDEO_AUTOPLAY;

 addChild(my_player);
 videoArray.push(my_player);
 my_player.source = my_videos[i]. @ URL;
 }
}

function positionPlayer():void {

 for (var i:int = 0; i < my_total; i++)
{
 videoArray[i].x = my_videos[i] . @PLAYER_X;
 videoArray[i].y = my_videos[i] . @PLAYER_Y;
 videoArray[i].width = my_videos[i] . @PLAYER_WIDTH;
 videoArray[i].height = my_videos[i] . @PLAYER_HEIGHT;

 }
}
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>

  <VIDEO PLAYER_X="450" PLAYER_Y="0" PLAYER_WIDTH="400" PLAYER_HEIGHT="300" PLAYER_SKIN_COLOR="0x0000FF" PLAYER_SKIN_ALPHA="1" VIDEO_AUTOPLAY="true" URL="test.flv"></VIDEO>

  <VIDEO PLAYER_X="0" PLAYER_Y="0" PLAYER_WIDTH="400" PLAYER_HEIGHT="300" PLAYER_SKIN_COLOR="0x333333" PLAYER_SKIN_ALPHA="1" VIDEO_AUTOPLAY="true" URL="test2.flv"></VIDEO>

</content>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

function goFullScreen():void
{
if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
} else {
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
}
}


//GREENSOCK LIQUID LAYOUT

var ls:LiquidStage = new LiquidStage(this.stage,900,600,900,600);

ls.attach(video_container_mc, ls.CENTER, false, true, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarMode;

var my_videos:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;
var player_skin_color:Number;
var player_skin_alpha:Number;
var auto_play:Boolean;

var videoArray:Array = new Array();

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {

 var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

 my_videos = myXML.VIDEO;
 my_total = my_videos.length();

makePlayer();
positionPlayer();
}


function makePlayer():void {

 for (var i:int = 0; i < my_total; i++) {

 var my_player:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
 my_player.name = "FLVplayer_" + i;
 my_player.skin = "SkinOverPlayFullscreen.swf";

 player_skin_color = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_SKIN_COLOR;
 player_skin_alpha = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_SKIN_ALPHA;
 auto_play = my_videos[i].@VIDEO_AUTOPLAY;

 my_player.skinBackgroundColor = player_skin_color;
 my_player.skinBackgroundAlpha = player_skin_alpha;
 my_player.autoPlay = auto_play;

 my_player.source = my_videos[i].@URL;
 videoArray.push(my_player);

 addChild(my_player);
 }
}

function positionPlayer():void {

 for (var i:int = 0; i < my_total; i++)
{
 videoArray[i].x = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_X;
 videoArray[i].y = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_Y;
 videoArray[i].width = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_WIDTH;
 videoArray[i].height = my_videos[i].@PLAYER_HEIGHT;

 }
}
```

Comment: Basically you did it all good, but you overrode the my_player in the loop. Instead of using a class variable I added a local variable in the loop and that instance will be added to the Array then.

Also the skin properties were declared after you added them to the player instances.

Comment: Thanks, your are absolutely right ! Now all the skins and positions works good. The Full screen no, but its strange, if I have for example four videos in xml, if I click in any full screen buttons, the last video in xml goes to full screen. And in second time that I click in a Video full screen all the videos crash and change positions. I think is a flash problem with full screen conflits.

Comment: if you posted the code where you handle the DisplayState changes we could see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I update my question, I use greensock to center layout on stage resize, the code works well with one video but with more...

Answer (score 0):

every time you add an FLVPlayback instance you create it on my_player.

instead of

```
my_player = new FLVPlayback();
```

try

```
//Create an array for the players
var my_players:Array = new Array();

//Add the player instances to the array
my_players.push (new FLVPlayback());
```

It should solve the other issues.

Rob

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, one question, for you method should I remove the videoArray ?

Comment: I tried a couple of things with your code but I have the same problems. I don't have errors but the videos don't apear.

Comment: Hi, sorry my answer is bullocks. Please see my new one.